# WPF trigger validation of a content control to enable or disable a button

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, button, locking

I have a UserControl with a ContentControl, which is a UserControl too.
This Content Control can be filled with any UserControl. I now want to lock a button in the parent UserControl, as long as the child UserControl doesn't have any errors.

Parrent:

The Content Control:

```
<ContentControl Name="SerializationLayerContentControl" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                Content="{Binding SerializationLayerConfiguration.ConfigView}">
</ContentControl>
```

and the button:

```
<Button Name="CreateTelegramBttn" Content="Create Telegram" Grid.Row="2" Click="CreateTelegramBttn_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=SerializationLayerContentControl}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
<Button Name="CreateAndSaveTelegramBttn" Content="Create and save" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="CreateAndSaveTelegramBttn_OnClick"></Button>
```

Child:

This is what I've got in the child UserControl

```
<ListBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding FieldDefinitionElements}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Label>
                    <Label.Content>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FieldDefConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Element.FieldName"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="Element.FieldType"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="Element.FieldLength"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Label.Content>
                </Label>
                <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                    <TextBox.Resources>
                        <validation:BindingProxy Data="{Binding Path=Element}" x:Key="proxy"/>
                    </TextBox.Resources>
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding
                            Path="Value"
                            Mode="TwoWay" 
                            UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                            NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"
                            NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"
                            NotifyOnValidationError="True"
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
                            ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <validation:FieldDefinitionElementRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">
                                <validation:FieldDefinitionElementRule.Wrapper>
                                        <validation:Wrapper StringFormat="{Binding Path=Data.FieldType, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" IntFormat="{Binding Path=Data.FieldLength, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
                                    </validation:FieldDefinitionElementRule.Wrapper>
                                </validation:FieldDefinitionElementRule>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Currently it's not working that the button is locked when there are any errors.

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this would be to hook the button up to a command that validates the child control in its `CanExecute` callback.  Simply have `CanExecute` return `false` if you want the button to be disabled.

Comment: The SerializationLayerContentControl will never have any validation errors. The TextBox will. But you won't be able to bind to this using an ElementName. You better implement your validation logic in a view model: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/.